# Nested loop in while

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, nested

I created a nested loop using For, here is the program code and the ouput, then I tried the while loop and get the different result:

- For:

```java
    public class ForBersarang {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = 5;
        for(int i = 0; i<=a; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<=i; j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

- While

```java
    public class WhileBersarang {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 0;
        int a = 5;
        int j = 0;
         while (i<=a) {
             while (j <= i) {
                 System.out.print("*");
                 j++;
             }
             i++;
             System.out.println("");
         }
    }
```

Comment: you need to put j inside the first loop other wise it woudn't be instanciated each i iteration and i-j will always equals to 1. See the answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is where you define `j`:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int i = 0;
      int a = 5;
    
      while (i<=a) {
         //here
         int j = 0;
         while (j <= i) {
             System.out.print("*");
             j++;
         }
         i++;
         System.out.println("");
     }
    }
}
```